# spring @Async not intercepted

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, threadpool, executorservice

I am tyring out a basic spring `@Async` example.

I have an interface like below

```
public interface AsyncInterface
{

    public void test();
}
```

Below is the implementation

```
@Service
public class AsyncImpl implements AsyncInterface
{

    @Async
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println( " This is seperate thread - let me sleep ");

        for ( int i = 0; i < 10 ; i ++ )
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am injecting the above implementation in another spring component and invoked the method annotated with `@Async`.

I have `<task:annotation-driven/>` in my `application-context`.

The `@Async` method is getting invoked sychronously and executes in the scope of the calling thread. The async behavior is not happening.

If i add a custom annotation to the test() method and if I write an aspect to intercept , it works.

For some reason, the `AsyncExecutorIntercpetor` is not getting triggered ( at least i could not see it in the logs ) .

Am I missing somethig here . Cant `@Async` be invoked from another spring component?

Thanks
Lives

This is how I am calling the async

I am calling Async from another spring @Service component

```
@Component
public class MyComponentImpl implements ComponentInterface
{
    @Autowired
    private AsyncInterface asyncInterface;

    @Override
    public void testAsyncInvocation() {
        logger.debug( " Before calling async ");
        asyncInterface.test();
        logger.debug( " After calling async ");
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <task:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Show us your configuration where the class is component scanned.

Comment: Show us your configuration and the invocation.

Comment: Please edit your question. Show us your context configuration.

Comment: Thansk - I was finding it difficult to put the code within comment.

Comment: I think i found the issue . The trigger point for this request was from the controller. The controller called a service which invoked the async component. When I  added <task:annotation-driven> to the web context as well , it worked . This component resides in the server - not sure why task annotation needs to be enabled in web context also .